# Android: App is crashing after uploading data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is 2 Edittext box and 1 button. Just after clicking the button, the data is uploaded on firebase but the app is getting crashed.

I don't even know what's going wrong. Everything is looking correct. Everything was working fine when there was only 1 EditText. But after adding another one the app is getting crashed. here is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {
        this.localView = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentupload, paramViewGroup, false);
    t1 = (TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.submit_title);
    userstoryText = (EditText) localView.findViewById(R.id.user_story);
    usernameText = (EditText) localView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    submitbtn = (Button) localView.findViewById(R.id.submit_story);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.upload_layout);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    submitbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return localView;

}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(userstoryText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the storybox is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else
    {
        AddData();
    }

}

public void AddData()
{
    String Story = userstoryText.getText().toString().trim();
    String Uname = usernameText.getText().toString().trim();

    HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dataMap.put("username", Uname);
    dataMap.put("storytext" , Story);

    databaseReference.push().setValue(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                userstoryText.setText("");
                usernameText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Submitted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

here is error log

```
    05-23 15:13:54.651 1314-1348/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [InputMethod] cancelBuffer: slot 1 is not owned by the producer (state = ACQUIRED)
05-23 15:14:04.780 1314-1348/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [InputMethod] cancelBuffer: slot 1 is not owned by the producer (state = ACQUIRED)
05-23 15:14:35.889 12168-12168/com.dcreativity.scribbledstories E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:181)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:166)
                                                                                         at com.dcreativity.scribbledstories.DataDisplayAdapter.<init>(DataDisplayAdapter.java:26)
                                                                                         at com.dcreativity.scribbledstories.FragmentHome$1.onDataChange(FragmentHome.java:77)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)


                                                                                     --------- beginning of crash
05-23 15:14:35.889 12168-12168/com.dcreativity.scribbledstories E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.dcreativity.scribbledstories, PID: 12168
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:181)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:166)
                                                                                      at com.dcreativity.scribbledstories.DataDisplayAdapter.<init>(DataDisplayAdapter.java:26)
                                                                                      at com.dcreativity.scribbledstories.FragmentHome$1.onDataChange(FragmentHome.java:77)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-23 15:14:37.443 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 3521, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
05-23 15:14:37.455 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
05-23 15:14:37.455 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-23 15:14:37.455 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
05-23 15:14:42.523 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 3529, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
05-23 15:14:42.523 2305-2387/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
```

This two lines are highlighted with blue underline in error log. a am extending fragment. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: `App is crashing after uploading data to Firebase` you need to share crash log with question

Comment: post your log cat

Comment: With what error?

Comment: @Bunny please see error log cat

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added error log. please check

Comment: At which line of code are you getting this error?

Comment: @NileshRathod i have added the crash log

Comment: @AlexMamo everything is working fine, but as soon as i click submit, the app is crashed. it should show the Toast message, but app is getting crashed. but even after crash the data is uploaded on firebase successfully.

Comment: @AlexMamo i couldn't find at which line error is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two edit text parameters in your program, so try to add an else if condition for **usernameText** as well.

```
if(userstoryText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the storybox is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } 
 else if(usernameText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the usernamebox is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } 

 else
    {
        AddData();
    }
```

If it Doesn't work add error log for the Question

Comment: Try to run Your App Using **"Debug" App** in Run Menu. Once you run it application will start in Emulator & a bottom window (Debug) will open/appear in Android Studio. Run the app, wherever it will crash, crash Log will be recorded in Debug window (Red Color). That's your crash/error Log.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the storybox is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"the storybox is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: not working.!  i have added line which was highlighted with blue underline in error log.  please see,

Comment: Change **also** in that line `getActivity()` to `getContext()`. Does it work now?

Comment: not working, that causes more errors. thanks anyway i am leaving this project now.

Comment: Oh, sorry the last screenshot shows the adapter class. My mistake. Please change `getActivity()` with `context`. It works, right?

Comment: not working. every goes well if i go with activity instead of fragment. so re-making the app with activity.

Comment: I didn't understood you but it should work when you are using the context. But don't also forget to change `Activity activity` with `Context context` in `public DataDisplayAdapter(@NoNull Activity context....)`. Should be `public DataDisplayAdapter(@NoNull Context context....)`.

Comment: And when you are initializing `DataDisplayAdapter`, use as I already said: `getContext()`.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?